# SQL query not working, using ideone. can't seem to spot error. extra eyes please. (simple query)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

having a little trouble why my query is not and displaying. I have looked over this and am not seeing any errors. I am using www.ideone.com to try and test some stuff though it's not working. If I could have an extra set of eyes that would be great. Thanks a bunch.

```html
create table Conflicts
(
 ConflictsID int(11),
 EmployeeID int(11),
 StartTime datetime,
 EndTime datetime,
 primary key(ConflictsID),
 foreign key(EmployeeID) references Schedule(EmployeeID)
);
create table Schedule
(
 ScheduleID int(11),
 PatientID int (11),
 EmployeeID int(11),
 AppointmentTime datetime,
 AppointmentDescription varchar(256),
 AppointmentNotes text,
 primary key (ScheduleID),
 foreign key(EmployeeID) references Conflicts(EmployeeID)
);

insert into Conflicts values (1,1,08:30:00,05:30:00);
select * from Conflicts;
```

Comment: Quote your datetimes - you're also missing the date component of the datetime.  It should look something like this: `'2016-04-06 08:30:00'`

Comment: Try putting the Date time inside quotes, like this '2012-04-06 08:30:00' EDIT : siyual beat me to it.

Comment: Should other values be quoted as well?

Comment: @HectorValde No, they're `INT` datatypes.  `INT` values should not be quoted.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was bugging me :)

Comment: Hey guys, quick question...does date time distinguish between 5AM and 5PM? for example both could fall on 2016-04-06, though how would I differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construct is not allowed because `EmployeeId` is not a unique key in `Schedule`:

```
foreign key(EmployeeID) references Schedule(EmployeeID)
```

I don't know what you want to represent but here are some ideas:

- Remove the foreign key reference entirely.
- Remove the `EmployeeId` from `Schedule`.
- Have a foreign key reference using `ConflictId`.
- Have a foreign key reference to `Employees`.

These are not necessarily mutually exclusive.

Comment: that was just a type, sorry about that but thanks for the answer!